# How do I iterate over a function in R?

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop, purrr

I am a beginner to R attempting to do some analysis of UN Comtrade data using the '[comtradr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/comtradr/vignettes/comtradr-vignette.html)' package.

For background, the package calls data from the Comtrade database (e.g. exports of fish from China for 1992 - 2021).

I know what I want to do but am struggling to work out how to do it.

In plain language, for countries in a list (country_list as below) I want to extract import data and then extract export data using the ct_search function.

Then, I hope to select relevant columns and plot each country's import / export in two separate line graph plots.

`country_list <- list("China", "United States", "India")` -- this should fill the reporters field in the ct_search function.

`trade_list <- list("exports", "imports")` -- this should fill the trade_direction field in the ct_search function.

I can do this for a single country as below, and could copy-paste the code for each country, but I know that's not efficient.

I'm guessing it's a mix of creating a function + for loops but I don't know how to do that in R .. can anyone give an example? Is it straightforward? So ideally the output would be six plots -- an import and then an export plot for China, the US and India.

Any help much appreciated!

```
--

library(tidyverse)
library(comtradr)

df <- ct_search(
  reporters = "China", 
  partners = "World",
  trade_direction = "exports",
  freq = "annual",
    commod_codes = "030520",
  type = "goods"
)

df2 <- df %>%
  select(year, qty, trade_value_usd)

ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = year, y = qty)) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't have to loop over your countries and trade directions to get your data as `ct_search` allows to pass character vectors (!!), i.e. use `c` instead of `list`. Note that e.g. for the `"United States"` you have to use `"USA"`.
2. To create your plots for each country you could `split` your data by country, put your plotting code inside a function and use e.g. `purrr::imap` to loop over the list of country data. Using `imap` makes it easy to pass the country names as a second argument to the plotting function which I add as the plot title. Instead of separate plots for imports and exports I use `facet_wrap` to create a plot of imports and exports for each country.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(comtradr)

country_list <- c("China", "United States" = "USA", "India")
trade_list <- c("exports", "imports")

df <- ct_search(
  reporters = country_list, 
  partners = "World",
  trade_direction = trade_list,
  freq = "annual",
  commod_codes = "030520",
  type = "goods"
)

df2 <- df %>%
  select(year, qty, trade_value_usd, reporter, trade_flow)

plot_fun <- function(.data, cntry) {
  ggplot(data = .data, aes(x = year, y = qty)) +
    geom_line(size = 1) +
    geom_point(size = 2) +
    facet_wrap(~trade_flow) +
    theme_bw() +
    labs(title = cntry)
}

df2 %>%
  split(.$reporter) %>%
  purrr::imap(plot_fun)
#> $China
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> $India
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> $USA
```

[image]